# Form Flickers Madly on Resize

Tags: c++, buffer, gdi, flicker

OK so for my main parent with common controls on my form everything flickers non stop when I resize it.

The fallowing controls are on my form:

1. Buttons
2. Static
3. RTF
4. Status Bar
5. Rebar With toolbars and some rebands

Now I set WM_ERASEBKGND to true so it wouldn't erase my forms background as they say that causes the flicker as well.

I also set my windows class hbrBackground to 0 and the same with the window class style which is also 0.

My parent form as the style WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW.

Also when I add WS_CLIPCHILDREN to my parent form it still flickers.

Now under my forms painting procedure I added this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
Temp_Rect=SSMAIN_RECT;
// Get DC for window
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

// Create an off-screen DC for double-buffering

hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, SSMAIN_WIDTH,SSMAIN_HEIGHT);


hOld   = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);

// Draw into hdcMem here

// Transfer the off-screen DC to the screen
Temp_Rect.left=-200;
Temp_Rect.top=-200;
FillRect(hdcMem, &Temp_Rect, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+7));
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0,  SSMAIN_WIDTH, SSMAIN_HEIGHT, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Free-up the off-screen DC
SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);
DeleteObject(hbmMem);
DeleteDC    (hdcMem);

EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
break;
```

[image: flickering]
<sub>(source: [phantomworksstudios.com](http://phantomworksstudios.com/cpp/flickeringpng.png))</sub>

I am so lost about this as I asked in another forum and someone mentioned to subclass my window for the paint procedure as that's what he did for his tab controls.

That somewhat confused me more because why would I have to sub class my forum when I can access the WM_PAINT without it?

Wouldn't it be the same as editing it under my Winproc rather then creating another one which will do the same thing if I'm not mistaken?

If you need anything else let me know please.

**Additional Notes:**

Also I changed the size of bitblt for a certain area.

Now heres the thing, the area where the bitblt is flickers while the rest of my windows doesn't as it leaves a trail of the other controls of the form when I resize it.

[image: flickeringarea]
<sub>(source: [phantomworksstudios.com](http://phantomworksstudios.com/cpp/flickeringarea.png))</sub>

Comment: I can't tell from you question but using `Begin/End/DeferWindowPos` helps prevent flickering a lot when resizing multiple controls.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, I forgot to mention that I use that as well. I no longer use SetWindowPos or MoveWindow within my application. Thanks for the tip though, really appreciate :D